# Adding Volume to stock chart with Moving average

Tags: python, charts, stock

The code below plot candle stick chart with moving average.
Can you please help to add volume with light blue color to it?
Thank you so much. HHC

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

df['SMA30']=df['AAPL.Close'].rolling(30).mean()
df['SMA100']=df['AAPL.Close'].rolling(100).mean()
print(df[:2])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close']), 
                
               go.Scatter(x=df.Date, y=df.SMA30, line=dict(color='orange', width=1)),  
               go.Scatter(x=df.Date, y=df.SMA100, line=dict(color='red', width=3)) 
                     ])
fig.update_layout(height =600)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
# !pip install ta
from ta.trend import MACD
from ta.momentum import StochasticOscillator

# Part 1: Candle Stick chart
candlesticks = go.Candlestick(
    x=df.index,
    open=df['Open'],
    high=df['High'],
    low=df['Low'],
    close=df['Close'],
    showlegend=False
)

# Part 2: Moving Average
Moving_Average_1 = go.Scatter(x=df.date, y=df.SMA30, line=dict(color='orange', width=1))
Moving_Average_2 = go.Scatter(x=df.date, y=df.SMA100, line=dict(color='red', width=3))


# Part 3: Volume Chart
volume_bars = go.Bar(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['Volume'],
    showlegend=False,
    marker={
        "color": "lightsteelblue",
    }
)

fig = go.Figure(candlesticks)
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(candlesticks, secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(Moving_Average_1, secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(Moving_Average_2, secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(volume_bars, secondary_y=False)



# hide weekend
fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])])
fig.update_layout(title="Price chart with MA and VOL", height=800)
fig.update_yaxes(title="Price $", secondary_y=True, showgrid=True)
fig.update_yaxes(title="Volume $", secondary_y=False, showgrid=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).